# Call for Proverb!

Tags: proverbs

I've been looking for a proverb like the one below for long, and some people say its root is British English.
But the more I search, the more I get disappointed.
Would any one please tell me the correct form of that proverb if any?

> I'm not rich enough to buy cheap things!

Answer (score 0):

The saying

> **I'm (we're) *not rich enough* to buy cheap {things/stuff}!**

happens to be essentially the same as

> **I'm (we're) *too poor* to buy cheap {things/stuff}**.

Variations on the latter include

> **Poor people can't afford cheap things**.
>   **The poor can't afford to buy cheap**.

---

Another possible proverb, yet with a slightly different meaning, is

> **Miserly/stingy always pays twice.**